# JQuery .on() Nested Click Event

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, click, event-binding

I have a quite complex form that fires AJAX calls to render partials that retrieve certain information.

I've hit a wall with a particular scenario where I want to bind an .on('click') event to an element that behaves like a button. The problem is, this element is nested deeply within other elements that are also destroyed during a partial refresh. Here's an example of the HTML.

```
<div id="locations_grid"><%= render 'table' %>
```

and for the partial:

```
<fieldset>
  <legend>List</legend>
  <div class="lists>
    <div class="project_list">
      <div id="pagination_link">
        <a class="more">
            More records
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

From my example, I want to bind the 'click' event to the class "more", which is nested in the arrangement of divs and a fieldset. Seeing as the "location_grid" renders the html, this would be the anchor point for the .on() event, seeing as it won't be destroyed after the partial is refreshed- so my initial attempt was:

```
$('#locations_grid').on('click','.more', function(){
  //do something
});
```

However, (to my understanding) I suspected this wouldn't work (and it didn't) because ".more" isn't the immediate child of "#locations_grid". So my attempts thus far have been various combinations of:

```
$('#locations_grid').on('click','fieldset .lists .project_list #pagination_link .more', function(){
  //do something
});
```

However, none seem to be successfully binding the click event to the ".more" class.

If anybody has any idea as to what I'm missing, the help would be well received!
Thanks Everyone,

Comment: have you tried `$(document).on('click','.more', function(){`?

Comment: @vijayP, yes, but it didn't work + I don't want to bind to the document, rather to the closest element that isn't destroyed.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, well it doesn't....

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Yes, I have indeed. As stated in the post- the element I am trying to bind the event to is static- and isn't destroyed after the the partial is refreshed. 

As outlined in the documentation http://api.jquery.com/on/ , I should be able to delegate to the decendants, but for some reason, the event is not bubbling up from .more. +1 for the downvote

Comment: Yes, this is only pseudo code- not actual source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved- issue turned out to be a problem with the Ruby on Rails asset pipeline not loading the javascript file.

To clarify, my initial implementation was correct.

```
$('#locations_grid').on('click','.more', function(){
  //do something
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use like below code

```
   $('body').on('click','fieldset .lists .project_list #pagination_link .more', function(){
      //do something
    });

 or

  $('body').on('click','.more', function(){
      //do something
    });
```

I think it will be work

Answer (score 0):

you can try this,it will apply click listener on all 'a' having class more;

```
    $('div').has(".more").on('click','.more', function(){
     //do something;
    });
```

Comment: Sorry Akshay, these aren't working. Think the problem with the first one is that the 'a' element is destroyed when the partial is re-render, thus also destroying the binding.